# Add Dynamic TextFields Through Dropdown Component Selection?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-js, office-ui-fabric, office-js-helpers

In the following project, I am creating a Task Pane using TypeScript and React in Microsoft Excel. When the Task Pane loads, it will only have a basic Dropdown with a few options. 
[image: Folder Path]

[image: AppPic.tsx]

```
import * as React from "react";
import Progress from "./Progress";
import { Dropdown, DropdownMenuItemType, IDropdownStyles, IDropdownOption } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dropdown';
//import TopLevel from "./Operations/TopLevel";
//import MakeItem from "./Operations/MakeItem";
//import RawMaterial from "./Operations/RawMaterial";
//import BuyItem from "./Operations/BuyItem";
export interface AppProps {
  title: string;
  isOfficeInitialized: boolean;
}

export interface AppState {

}

export default class App extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({

    });
  }

  render() {
    const { title, isOfficeInitialized } = this.props;
    const dropdownStyles: Partial<IDropdownStyles> = {
      dropdown: { width: 300 }
    };
    const options: IDropdownOption[] = [
      { key: 'blank', text: '' },
      { key: 'topLevelMake', text: 'Parents', itemType: DropdownMenuItemType.Header },
      { key: 'topLevel', text: 'TOP LEVEL' },
      { key: 'make', text: 'MAKE ITEM' },
      { key: 'divider_1', text: '-', itemType: DropdownMenuItemType.Divider },
      { key: 'Purchased', text: 'Purchases', itemType: DropdownMenuItemType.Header },
      { key: 'rawMaterial', text: 'RAW MATERIAL' },
      { key: 'buyItem', text: 'BUY ITEM' },
    ];
    ;
    if (!isOfficeInitialized) {
      return (
        <Progress title={title} logo="assets/logo-filled.png" message="Please sideload your addin to see app body." />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="ms-welcome">
            <Dropdown
              label="Operation"
              key="dropDownKey"
              options={options}
              styles={dropdownStyles}
            />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After the response from Klas, I have changed my code around a bit, but am having troubles because there are no errors thrown around. I have my App.tsx, my TopLevel.tsx, and the new file I created because of Klas called Dropdown.tsx. For now i will forget about "Make", I am just trying to understand the logic. What am i doing wrong here?

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Dropdown from "./Operations/Dropdown";
export interface AppProps {
  title: string;
  isOfficeInitialized: boolean;
}
export interface AppState {

}

function App() {
  return <Dropdown />;
}

export default App;
```

**Dropdown.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import TopLevel from './TopLevel';
import { useState } from 'react';
const Dropdown = (): React.ReactElement => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("none");
    let Form: any;
    switch (value) {
      case "TopLevel":
        Form = <TopLevel title="title" logo="logo" message="message" />;
        break;

      case "Make":
        Form = <div />;
        break;

      default:
        Form = <div />;
        break;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          id="lang"
          onChange={event => event?.target?.value && setValue(event.target.value)}
          value={value}
        >
          <option value="select">Select</option>
          <option value="TopLevel">TopLevel</option>
          <option value="Make">Make</option>
        </select>
        {Form}
      </div>
    );
  };
  export default Dropdown;
```

**TopLevel.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface TopLevelProps {
  title: string;
  logo: string;
  message: string;
}
export default class TopLevel extends React.Component<TopLevelProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>TopLevel</div>
        <input placeholder="Part Number" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting.
[image]

Comment: That screenshot looks like something is confused by the optional chaining, `?.` which is supported by TypeScript 3.7 and forward https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining Easiest would probably be to replace it with normal chaining.

Comment: https://blaipratdesaba.com/react-typescript-cheatsheet-form-elements-and-onchange-event-types-8c2baf03230c    Would changing the onChange like the last one in this article help or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic program that has a dropdown and will show different forms based on the value of the dropdown.

```js
const Dropdown = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("none");

  let Form: any;
  switch (value) {
    case "TopLevel":
      Form = <TopLevel title="title" logo="logo" message="message" />;
      break;

    case "Make":
      Form = <Make />;
      break;

    default:
      Form = <div />;
      break;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        id="lang"
        onChange={event => event?.target?.value && setValue(event.target.value)}
        value={value}
      >
        <option value="select">Select</option>
        <option value="TopLevel">TopLevel</option>
        <option value="Make">Make</option>
      </select>
      {Form}
    </div>
  );
};

export interface TopLevelProps {
  title: string;
  logo: string;
  message: string;
}

class TopLevel extends React.Component<TopLevelProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>TopLevel</div>
        <input placeholder="Part Number" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Make extends React.Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return <div>Make</div>;
  }
}

function App() {
  return <Dropdown />;
}
```

Note how the `switch` lets you have different forms for different values.

The `DropDown` component you are using also has an `onChange` property, so that should be possible to wire up in a similar way, with different form renderings for different values.

Comment: Thank you very much @Klas Mellbourn! I will do a deep dive on this and try to adapt this in my code and get back to you!

Comment: Hi Klas Melbourn, what am i missing in my update code above? Am i putting something in the wrong place? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify exactly what is not working? Is the dropdown there? Can you select values from it? Is nothing shown when you do?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my npm Error. Sorry for confusion